# What factors influence in the first games to enter in a League?

Tags: league-of-legends

Well, I'm new doing ranked and I was surprised when, my team won the 5 games to enter a league and we get Bronze III. A friend told me that they with only 4 victories in the first 4 games they were Silver IV.

So I was wondering that what factors influence to get in a League, because it's not only how many wins we do at first 5 games.

The personal MMR from every one of the team can be a factor?

Comment: I believe it is based on how good the teams you face are. so luck of the draw. you might have faced 4 bronze teams then lost to the only silver team so you got stuck in bronze. Also if you need an extra guy to fill im looking for a team, i play everyday and gave up on solo que.

Comment: My first 5 wins landed us in Gold II. I can't believe the difference between two teams with 5 wins ... I would feel so shafted ending up in Bronze III

Comment: I think it can depend on how everyone on the team has done in ranked ladders, as well as your team's performance in previous seasons.

Comment: @SadlyNot Yes, we feel that way. Well, we are trying to get Silver at least but playing through the League, but we still thinking about why Bronze III...

Comment: easiest way to figure it out is by which color team you were in your matches, purple team is supposedly the team to beat(or so i've heard before) so blue team is like the underdog, if blue team wins, it counts as a greater win than if purple had won. this can easily explain why you were placed into Bronze III even though you won all of your matches. (again this is all based on things I've heard)

Comment: I've looked around and even asked two Riot employees and couldn't get an answer. I am not sure there is a published 'official' answer to this question.

Comment: @SimonL Thanks, I asked too, but the same for me.

Comment: In team it does'n really matter cause you can't blame your mate to be trolls like in solo Q ;-) if you really deserve to get to Gold you will go there pretty fast :-D

Comment: @Hystic Actually it can be very tough to climb to Gold from Bronze. Keep in mind LP gain is clamped as you reach the next Tier, meaning you end up playing 20ish games in Division I for any given Tier. Going up two Tiers can prove extremely draining. His ranked team will likely have to play 50+ games to reach Gold, and that's with consistently good performance ...

Comment: @Mueretee Are you playing 5v5 or 3v3 ranked?

Comment: @SadlyNot 5v5 ranked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I know, I'm sorry if it's not a complete answer.

In 5v5, everyone's elo is important, because Riot will match you against a team with similar elo. This is important because it's not just winning that matters, but who you win against.

For instance, if you win 5 games against 5 Bronze III teams you'll be placed into Bronze III-II. But if you win 3 games against Gold 3 and lose twice against Platinum or Gold I, you'll likely be placed into gold.

In short, it's not just the quantity, but the quality of wins that matters.

Comment: @Nicholas1024 Thank you very much! :)

Comment: No problem. After all, I learned something from your answer as well. :)